# Difference between the max date and the penultimate max for specific employee - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date

Bit stuck on a problem. Trying to find the difference between two dates in postgreSQL.

I have a table emp with many employees in it:

```
emp_id, date 

1, 31-10-2017 

1, 08-08-2017 

1, 02-06-2017
```

I want it to look like this:

```
emp_id, max_date, penultimate_date, difference 

1, 31-10-2017, 08-08-2017, 84 days
```

Obviously you can use `max(date)` and `group by` the `emp_id`, however how do you retrieve the penultimate date. I have used a few functions like:

```
order by date desc limit 1 offset 1
```

I have also tried to put these in sub queries but that hasn,t worked as there are many employee numbers and I need one row for each employee.

Can anyone help???

Thanks,

pp84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as kindly suggested by @Haleemur Ali, `order by date desc limit 1 offset 1` would not work with several emp_id:

```
t=# with d(emp_id, date)as (values(1, '31-10-2017'::date),(1, '08-08-2017'),(1, '02-06-2017' ),(2,'2016-01-01'),(2,'2016-02-02'),(2,'2016-03-03'))
select distinct  emp_id
, max(date) over (partition by emp_id) max_date
, nth_value(date,2) over (partition by emp_id)  penultimate_date
, max(date) over (partition by emp_id) - nth_value(date,2) over (partition by emp_id) diff
from d
;
 emp_id |  max_date  | penultimate_date | diff
--------+------------+------------------+------
      2 | 2016-03-03 | 2016-02-02       |   30
      1 | 2017-10-31 | 2017-08-08       |   84
(2 rows)

Time: 0.756 ms
```

Comment: i feel like this solution will not work for multiple employees.

Comment: @HaleemurAli thank you for the hint - surely `limit 1` not capable of several rows :)

Comment: thank you for updating your answer. I always forget about the `nth_value` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH emps (emp_id, date) AS (
    VALUES (1, '2017-10-31'::DATE)
         , (1, '2017-08-08'::DATE)
         , (1, '2017-08-08'::DATE)
)

SELECT DISTINCT ON (emp_id) 
    emp_id
  , "date" max_date
  , LEAD("date") OVER w penultimate_date
  , "date" - LEAD("date") OVER w difference
FROM emps 
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY emp_id)
ORDER BY emp_id, date DESC
```

When ordered in descending order, the `LEAD("date") w` will give the value of the date value from the next row.

The `DISTINCT ON` limits the resultset to 1 row (the first row encountered) per `emp_id`.

With our ordering this first row must contain the greatest date, and the `LEAD(...) over w` therefore returns the penultimate date. This gives us the following result:

```
 emp_id |  max_date  | penultimate_date | difference
--------+------------+------------------+------------
      1 | 2017-10-31 | 2017-08-08       |         84
(1 row)
```